# SpriteKit: How do you have a first level at 1 instead of 0?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The point of my game is when I touch the screen, the game starts. When started, I have a moving Player and a Target. If I touch the screen whilst the game is playing and the Player and Target are colliding, I score a point. At level one, there is only one point to score, so I'd hit the target and move straight on to level Two. On level TWO, there are TWO points to score before going on to level THREE. My problem is, when I first start the game, on which I want to be level ONE, it actually starts on level ZERO, then goes on to level ONE which is weird... Here's my code. Cheers!

```
var levelLabel = UILabel()

var levelText = UILabel()

var showLevel = UILabel()

var currentLevel = Int()
var currentScore = Int()
var highLevel = Int()

func targetTouched(){
    if intersected == true{
        Target.removeFromParent()
        addTarget()
        intersected = false
currentScore -= 1
        levelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
        showLevel.text = "\(currentScore)"
        if currentScore <= 0{
            nextLevel()   
        }
    }
    else if intersected == false{

        died()
    }
func nextLevel(){
    currentLevel += 1
    currentScore = currentLevel
    levelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
    showLevel.text = "\(currentScore)"
    won()
    if currentLevel > highLevel{
        highLevel = currentLevel
        let Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        Defaults.setInteger(highLevel, forKey: "highLevel")

    }
```

Comment: in informatics, 0 is the 1

Comment: Change `var currentLevel = Int()` to `var currentLevel = 1`!

Comment: @luk2302 - Feeling such a idiot right now! :P I changed both the var currentLevel and currentScore from Int() to 1. Thank you!!